# Need help finding the largest number and the smallest number of a group of numbers

Tags: c++

As the title says, I need help finding the largest number and the smallest number in a group of numbers then display it at the end. The group of numbers is randomly generated every time. Would also greatly appreciate it if someone could explain how to make it so it displays the random numbers that were chosen and not the totals while still calculating the totals (for the average). Thanks :)

p.s sorry if the indentation is weird, this is my first post here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Total = 0; // total of all numbers
    int AOT; //amount of times
    int i;

    cout << "How many random numbers should this machine make?" << endl;
    cin >> AOT;
    cout << endl;

    srand(time(0));

    for(i=1;i<=AOT;i++)
    {
        //makes a random number and sets it to the total
        Total = Total + (rand()%10);
        //just some fancy text
        cout << "The total after " << i << " random number/s is ";
        cout << Total << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // ALL THE DATA ON THOSE NUMBERS
    cout << "The amount of numbers there were is " << AOT << endl;
    cout << "The average for the random numbers is " << Total / AOT << endl;
}
```

Comment: but you are only generating the random numbers and concatenating those to the Total variable... where is the findMax function??

Comment: If the indentation is weird, why don't you fix it?

Comment: You did not search for other questions about "maximum" and "average" did you?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the random numbers as they are generated and print the temporary number to show the group of number to users.
Initialize to variables, to store smallest and largest number of that group, to that temporary number.

Compare the number random number as they are generated to find whether it is smaller than 'smallest' or larger than 'largest' and assign them to the variables accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int smallest, largest, temp;
    int AOT; //amount of times
    int i;

    cout << "How many random numbers should this machine make?" << endl;
    cin >> AOT;
    cout << endl;

    srand(time(0));
    cout<<" Random Numbers are:";
    smallest = rand()%10;
    cout<<smallest<<'\t';
    largest = smallest;
    for(i=1;i<AOT;i++)
    {
        temp = (rand()%10);
        cout<<temp<<'\t';
        if(temp < smallest)
        {
            smallest =  temp;
        }
        else if(temp > largest)
        {
            largest = temp;
        }

    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // ALL THE DATA ON THOSE NUMBERS
    cout << "The smalles number is " << smallest << endl;
    cout << "The largest number is " << largest << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please extend the explanation of your answer. Why is an array needed for achieving OPs goals?

Comment: I see no need for any array to accomplish the OP's task whatsoever.

Comment: Just an easy way out!

Okay will try to expand upto my knowledge. Thank you for pushing me!

Comment: @Yunnosch Done. This is the extend of my knowledge currently. If you wanna add something. I kindly request you to.

Comment: @WhozCraig  Done. This is the extend of my knowledge currently. If you wanna add something. I kindly request you to.

Comment: Seems a decent answer now. Would be better with explanation, as it is, it still is a code-only answer. Those make StackOverflow seem like a gratis coding service. Also, StackOverflowers tend not to upvote answers to duplicate questions (the hint at duplicate is older than your answer).

Comment: @Yunnosch Didn't know that. thanks.